# EF Generic Repository get Id from new inserted generic entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

All my entities has property Id. All my tables in database has auto-generated integer identity Id as primary key.

I have generic method to Create entities.

Is there any way to get entity Id after entity inserted in to database?

```
   public override int Create<T>(T entity)
    {
        string entitySet = GetEntitySetName<T>();
        _context.AddObject(entitySet, entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return <Id Here>; //TODO Return Id here
    }
```

In simple(not generic) repository i may just return Entity.Id,  but how to get the same behavior in generic repository?
 I may have base entity class for all entities which contains int property Id but is there any way to get it work without implementing this inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution:

```
 public override TR Create<T, TR>(T entity)
    {
        string entitySet = GetEntitySetName<T>();
        _context.AddObject(entitySet, entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        //Returns primaryKey value
        return (TR)context.CreateEntityKey(entitySet, entity).EntityKeyValues[0].Value;                       
    }
```

Where T: entity type, TR: entity PK type.

Comment: Is it possible to get the id before calling savechanges?

Comment: @Jeroen There is two ways of doing this, If you want to use int as PK in that case first you need to insert empty record to get new Id generated by database, otherwhise you may use Guid as a PK, in that case you may generate PK's directtly in your code by calling Guid.NewGuid()

Comment: please show how to call your `Create()` function which will return PK value. thanks

Answer (score 16):

This can actually be dead simple;

```
// Project is is object/table, no POCO here.

var newProj = new Project();
newProj.Name = "Blah project";

var db = new AppDataContextname();

db.Projects.AddObject(newProj);

// at this point, newProj.ID is NOT set

db.SaveChanges(); // record is added to db.
// now, the ID property of the Project object is set!!!

// if the last ID in that table is '25', and you have auto-increment,
// then the object's ID property will now be 26!
Console.WriteLine(newProj.ID); // will output "26"
```

Racked my brain on how to get the ID back for a long time until I realized that the above code works. Works in Linq-To-SQL and EF4.

Answer (score 4):

With POCO entities, you'd have to use an interface, reflection, or `dynamic`.

With `EntityObject` entities you can read the `EntityKey` property.

Comment: Thanks, Interface is the better way, but temporary i will go with dynamic.
            'dynamic currentEntity = entity;'
            'return currentEntity.Id;'

Answer (score 2):

```
 With reflection you can obtain the Id property.


public override int Create<T>(T entity)
    {
        string entitySet = GetEntitySetName<T>();
        _context.AddObject(entitySet, entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();

         var idProperty = item.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(entity,null);
         return (int)idProperty;
    }
```

Comment: This works but it can be a performance drag .. reflection is slow (many argues).