# Get the model update the Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

In entity framework when you commit a new item it does not get his id updated according to the database. For example:

```
public class A  {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime LastUpdateUtc {get; set;}
}
```

Now when I add a new  A to my repository:

```
A a = new A();
a.LastUpdateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
repo.Add(a);
repo.SaveChange();
a.Id; // still == 0
```

Even if I search for the eleement in my repository I get an A but the Id is still equal to 0.

```
A a = repo.Asquerable().OrderByDescending(a => a.LastUpdateUtc ).First();
a.Id; // still == 0
```

Does someone know how do I tell entity framework to update the Id feild from what the database have compute?

Thanks

Comment: Is the ID column an identity column in the database or not? An int is defaulted to 0, so this is why it is always 0 - you are not setting it.

Comment: Yes it is an Id in my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I did make it work by adding the attirbute:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The entity framework will automatically retrieve the new automatically generated ID field from the database if your ID column has an AUTONUMBER property. Have you looked in the database to ensure that your ID data isn't actually 0?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please

```
public override TR Create<T, TR>(T entity)
{
    string entitySet = GetEntitySetName<T>();
    _context.AddObject(entitySet, entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    //Returns primaryKey value
    return (TR)context.CreateEntityKey(entitySet, entity).EntityKeyValues[0].Value;                       
} // Where T: entity type, TR: entity PK type
```

And if it's ok - take a look here [EF Generic Repository get Id from new inserted generic entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547950/ef-generic-repository-get-id-from-new-inserted-generic-entity)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
A a = repo.Asquerable().OrderByDescending(a => a.LastUpdateUtc ).First();
a.Id;
```

try

```
A queryA = repo.Asquerable().OrderByDescending(a => a.LastUpdateUtc);
queryA.First().Id;
```

`a` in this case is an entity (not query) and does not change