# Get Id of Generic Entity of EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-6

I write a generic repository to CRUD in EF.In add method is written like this

```
public class GenericRepo<T> where T : class
{
        //Create
        public static void Add(CellPhoneProjectEntities dbContext, T entity)
        {
            dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

works fine by i want to get first element of the Entity(Primary key ,Identity column )

```
public static long Add(CellPhoneProjectEntities dbContext, T entity,long id)
        {
            dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            var pk = entity.ElementType.KeyMembers[0];
            //Something like first elemnt by generic
            return pk as Long;
        }
```

can anyone help to get First element(Id) of entity after insertion?

EDIT: EF database first and my primary key is not named Id..

Rather it is TableNameId eg. Table **ProjectMaster** has primary key **ProjectMasterId**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework code first. Find primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253943/entity-framework-code-first-find-primary-key)

Comment: Answer is based on EF 4.1 but my EF in 6.1.3

Comment: may be helped : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547950/ef-generic-repository-get-id-from-new-inserted-generic-entity

Comment: Generic repository, yay for pattern abuse.

Answer (score 2):

When you assume that the element's ID is a `long` that's the first element of they key, you're making explicitly *non-generic* assumptions. Not all entities have a `long` key, or a key at all.

If you have this assumption, it's best to have it *explicitly* stated in the code. Create a base entity class with an ID, and ensure all entities inherit it. That way you know each entity has a compatible ID. If your table's column is named differently, you can use the `[Column]` attribute to map between them:

```
public abstract class EntityBase 
{
     public virtual long Id {get; set;}
}

public class MyEntity : EntityBase
{
    [Column("TableId"]
    public override long Id {get;set;}
}

public long Add(DbContext context, T entity) where T : EntityBase
{
    var storedEntity = dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return storedEntity.Id; // Will always have the property.
}
```

Comment: int is very short for a table identity ..so why not long because it is very handy not think about future ranges

Comment: i also tried this answer but no all Table contains Id rather TableId ..

Comment: Your EF entities don't have to be named the same as your DB entities. You can use the [Column] attribute to specify it.

Comment: Also, I didn't write anything about `int` vs `long`, so your first comment was probably directed at someone else.

Answer (score 0):

After trying I find a temporary solution..but better answer is still not found ...

1 Mistake I made that not every entity (Table) contains id ..it is rather `TableId`

so my temporary solution is return the entity and get the value of identity column after added to db.

```
 //Create ///Get ID of the table
        public static T Add(CellPhoneProjectEntities dbContext, T entity, long id)
        {
            dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return entity;
        }
```

and to Get id

```
ServiceMaster master=some entity;;
long id=GenericRepo<ServiceMaster>Add(dbContext,master).ServiceMasterId;
```